# Only last message is sent in sendMultipartTextMessage in Samsung Galaxy S3

Tags: android, smsmanager

A strange issue is happening only last message in the arraylist is being sent when using sendMultipartTextMessage in Samsung Galaxy S3 phone.

I tried the same code in Nexus 5, Galaxy Nexus all the messages are sent.

```
 ArrayList<String> messagelist = smsManager.divideMessage (smsTextwithotherdetails);
 Log.e("SIZE","OF Message"+messagelist.size());
 smsManager.sendMultipartTextMessage(smsNumber, null, messagelist, null, null);
```

The log of messagelist.size show the multipart correctly.

Strange it is not working in Samsung Galaxy S3?

Did anybody face the same issue when using sendMultipartTextMessage?

Thanks!